# Can C++ main be inside a class and call a derived class?

Tags: c++

I'm new to using class/objects. I'm trying to write something like this:

```
class C1{

    main ()
    {
         C2::foo();
    }
};

class C2:public C1
{
public:
    foo()
    {
    }
};
```

It compiler complains C2 is not a class or namespace when C2::foo() is called.  If I move class C2 definition in front, then C1 is not defined.  What can be done here?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a class with a member function named `main`, but it will *not* be *the* `main` that gets invoked to start your program -- that needs to be a global function (outside any class or namespace). But yes, a member function named `main` is perfectly fine (§3.6.1/3):

> The name `main` is not otherwise reserved. [*Example*: member functions, classes, and enumerations can be called `main`, as can entities in other namespaces. -- *end example*]

As far as how to arrange your code, you typically end up with something like this:

```
class C1 { 
    int main();
};

class C2 : public C1 { 
public:
    int foo();
    // or perhaps: static int foo();
};

int C1::main() {
    C2::foo(); // given `C2::static int foo();`
    // otherwise: C2 c; c.foo();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

main should not be inside of a class at all.

Answer (score 1):

No, `main` cannot be inside a class. (Just to make it clear, you can have functions called `main` in a class, but they won't be the entry point of your program.)

(C++ Standard n3337, section 3.6.1)

> A program shall contain a **global** function called `main`, which is the
>   designated start of the program.

Answer (score 1):

a `main` *can* be inside of a class. But its not the same as the entry point `main`, which must be global!

Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class C2 {
   public:
     void foo() {
        cout << "Foo!";
    }
};

class C1 {
   public:
     void main() { // not the same as the entry-point `main`
       cout << "What?";
       b.foo();
     }
  private: 
     B b;
};



int main() //actual entry point `main`
{
   A a;
   a.main();
   return 0;
}
```

Note however, your code is seriously flawed, for one - the member functions *must* have a return type.(`void` if you're not returning anything). Secondly, `foo` is an object function, which means it can only be invoked with an object of type `C2`.

Comment: You are confusing readers by saying `Contrary to the answers, a main can be inside of a class.`. In your example, main *is not* inside class, there is only a method called main, what is much different from `main` we're talking about. Your `main` still *is not* inside class. A valid way of saying what you want to say is like Jerry Coffin is doing in next answer.

Comment: @Spook, yeah edited it out. I don't recall what I read that made me write "contrary to the answers" statement. But it was something to do with one of the answers posted at that time.

Comment: I'd still clear it out like: `You can write program in object manner by creating static function called main in some class. It still has to be called from global main function though`.